# Calculating and proving the generating function for the recursion $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 3$?

Tags: generating-functions

I'm trying to calculate the generating function for the recursion $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 3$. I've found all sorts of related facts, like the OEIS series of the coefficients (A001333), or the *actual equation* $a_n = \frac{(1-\sqrt2)^n + (1+\sqrt2)^n}2$, but I can't find the generating function. How would I do this, and what's the answer?

EDIT: So now I know the answer is $\frac{1-x}{1 - 2x - x^2}$. But how would I prove that?

Comment: $\frac12((1-\sqrt2)^1+(1+\sqrt2)^1)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OEIS itself has this line in the formula section of A001333:

```
G.f.: (1 - x) / (1 - 2*x - x^2) = 1 / (1 - x / (1 - 2*x / (1 + x))). - Michael Somos, Sep 02 2012
```

"G.f." indicates a generating function in the OEIS, so you are looking for $\frac{1-x}{1-2x-x^2}$. Similarly, "E.g.f" indicates an exponential generating function.

Comment: Thank you. So would the generating function be the sum from 0 to infinity of (1 - x) / (1 - 2*x - x^2)?

Comment: @DrewWeisserman No, what I gave you _is_ the generating function. (To shift the sequence forward or backward, multiply or divide by $x$.)

Comment: Okay, so I would just replace x with whatever term in the sequence I need to find the x-th term of the sequence? Sorry, my math teacher didn't explain this well.

Comment: @DrewWeisserman You do not substitute the term number into a generating function. Rather, you take the Maclaurin series expansion of it, and the series coefficients form the sequence.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @DrewWeisserman Please accept my answer since you found it helpful. (Check the green tick to the left.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how I would prove this?

Comment: @DrewWeisserman I don't know, but for linear recurrences like this it should be easy.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Unfortunately, my prof didn't explain this subject at all, so I'm kind of stuck in the water. Hopefully, someone else will respond. Thanks for the answer, though!!!

Comment: But that is the GF for the given recurrence but with initial conditions $a_0=a_1=1$.

Comment: In that case it's $(1+x)/(1-2x-x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to derive the generating function.

It's important to note the range of $n$ for which the recursion holds:
$$a_n= 2a_{n-1}  +a_{n-2}$$
for $\color{red}{n \ge 2}$, with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=3$.
We can use the initial conditions and the Kronecker delta function to rewrite the recursion in a form that holds for all $n \ge 0$:
$$a_n= 2a_{n-1}  +a_{n-2} + \delta_{0n} +\delta_{1n}$$
(You should study this equation to see how it works.)

Now multiply by $x^n$
$$a_n x^n = 2a_{n-1} x^n +a_{n-2} x^n + \delta_{0n} x^n +\delta_{1n} x^n$$
and sum over $n$, with the result
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2a_{n-1} x^n +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n-2} x^n + 1 + x$$
If we define $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
then the previous equation becomes
$$f(x) = 2x f(x) + x^2 f(x) +1 +x$$
which you can now solve for $f(x)$, with the result
$$f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-2x-x^2}$$